# Placement of refresh cta

Tags: user-expectation, dashboard, experience

We have one widget wherein we need to place a refresh CTA on clicking will load new information on another item. [image]
In an ideal sceanrio Refresh should be placed at widget level which gives clear info to user and ux wise it is correct.

What are the other possible options for placing refresh CTA? Wouldn't want to change the position of Create & View all CTA as we are getting good no.of clicks.

Carousel is one possible option. Need few more options

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that "Refresh" would only refresh the content inside the widget right now? Feeds and News are two things that users might expect to refresh as well. Are those ever manually refreshed by the user?

Comment: For now the refresh is applicable for the content inside the widget. News and feeds do get updates on page refresh

Answer (score 1):

Because there are areas on the page that seem "refreshable" but aren't (like Feeds), you'll want to keep that Refresh action inside the bounds of the widget area.

In a lot of cases with refreshable content, it's nice to let the user know how old the information is, so they can decide if it's time to refresh. I'd add something like this to the bottom of the widget:

[image: A card with a refresh pattern at the bottom]

Comment: We did try this option but the refresh CTA was looking hanging if the content in the card is limited. The card design is borderless. I'll give it a shot. Thanks